# Is one memory leak normal for an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c++

I tested my app with the Leaks tool to determine leaks. I resolved all leaks but one.
This one seems difficult to remove. I am working on it but not sure what will remove the leak.

**Is it normal for apps to have one or two leaks which don't leak that much memory over the usage of the app?**

Comment: I'm sure if you took all the apps on the store, a lot of them would have memory leaks, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't fix them...

Comment: does the leak threaten your application's ability to function? i.e. how big is the leak?

Comment: Sometimes these leaks occur due to bugs in the framework itself so I wouldn't beat yourself up over it. In the ideal world, however, there would be no bugs, and no leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory leak is a bug much like any other bug. They are very easy to measure, though, and in some situations they can cause fatal crashes, so a lot of effort is put into dealing with memory leaks.

But most apps, memory leaks or not, have bugs in them. And a bug isn't automatically a blocker just because the bug causes leaking of memory.